# UIWebView displaying a Page - Zooming Out and Staying Zoomed Out

Tags: objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, zooming

This is incredibly annoying. Sometimes I'll be viewing a PDF that's quite long (by height of pages, not length of document), so I cant get the full page on the view without zooming out, and the moment I take my fingers off the screen, it snaps back to full width. This means, I can only comfortably view a small section of the PDF page.

I need to snap to height and not width, but it wont allow me to zoom further out than the width of the app.

Here is my setup:

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 1024, 704)];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.25;
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: `[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];` might be your problem. Try setting it to `NO` and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: When it's NO, it doesn't allow any kind of scaling, the pinch/zoom procedure doesn't work.

Comment: Ah ok, it's been a while since I coded in Objective-C. I'll probably go back to it after my current project.